# Turning off debugger in release mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio, benchmarkdotnet

I have Build set to Release mode.

[image]

I'm running my `.NET Core 3.1` Console App with `Benchmark DotNet`. But it tells me, that

> Summary -> Benchmark was executed with attached debugger

How to turn off debugger completely in `Release` build mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debug -> Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5)

[image: Screenshot of "Start Without Debugging"]

Comment: Still, `Benchmark` tells me, that im running my app in `debug` mode

Comment: @michasaucer What *exactly* does it tell you? What's the exact message?

Comment: After all tests, its print that `Summary` from my original post

Comment: @michasaucer So it tells you that you've got an attached debugger, *not* that you're running your app in `debug` mode? (Those are two very different things)

Comment: I think so. Where can i find that `attached` property in my app? For debugger of course

Comment: What do you mean, `attached` property? Your app can be built in a Debug or Release configuration: Debug builds are slower, but are easier to debug (*if* you attach a debugger to them); Release builds are quicker, but harder to debug. You can run both Debug and Release builds. When one is running, you can choose to attach a debugger (regardless of whether it's a Debug or Release build). When you click "Start Debugging", Visual Studio will start your application and then attach a debugger. When you click "Start Without Debugging", Visual Studio just starts your application: no debugger.

Answer (score 2):

You can just run it from command line:

```
dotnet run -c Release
```